# Why doesn't backsubstituting the result of Solve[] give the expected result?

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have this matrix

```
a = {{2, -2, -4}, {-2, 5, -2}, {-4, -2, 2}}
```

I then solved an equation with one missing entry. The equation is of the form
Inverse[p].a.p == q
where p is the 3x3 matrix with the missing entry (x5) and q is a given 3x3 matrix.

```
Solve[Inverse[( {
      {1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/3},
      {-2/Sqrt[5], 2/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/6},
      {0, x5, -2/3}
     } )].a.( {
     {1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/3},
     {-2/Sqrt[5], 2/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/6},
     {0, x5, -2/3}
    } ) == ( {
    {6, 0, 0},
    {0, 6, 0},
    {0, 0, -3}
   } )]
```

Mathematica can solve this easily and I get x5 -> -(Sqrt[5]/3)  as the result.
However if I check it, the result ist very weird:

```
In[2]:= Inverse[( {
    {1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/3},
    {-2/Sqrt[5], 2/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/6},
    {0, -Sqrt[5]/3, -2/3}
   } )].a.( {
   {1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/3},
   {-2/Sqrt[5], 2/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/6},
   {0, -Sqrt[5]/3, -2/3}
  } )

Out[2]= {{6/5 - (2 (-(2/Sqrt[5]) - 2 Sqrt[5]))/Sqrt[5], 
  8/5 + (2 (-(2/Sqrt[5]) - 2 Sqrt[5]))/(3 Sqrt[5]), -(4/Sqrt[5]) + 
   1/3 (2/Sqrt[5] + 2 Sqrt[5])}, {-((
    2 (-(8/(3 Sqrt[5])) + (4 Sqrt[5])/3))/Sqrt[5]) + (
   4/(3 Sqrt[5]) + (4 Sqrt[5])/3)/Sqrt[5], 
  10/3 + (2 (-(8/(3 Sqrt[5])) + (4 Sqrt[5])/3))/(3 Sqrt[5]) + (
   4 (4/(3 Sqrt[5]) + (4 Sqrt[5])/3))/(3 Sqrt[5]), (4 Sqrt[5])/3 + 
   1/3 (8/(3 Sqrt[5]) - (4 Sqrt[5])/3) - 
   2/3 (4/(3 Sqrt[5]) + (4 Sqrt[5])/3)}, {0, 0, -3}}
```

the expected result should be

```
( {
  {6, 0, 0},
  {0, 6, 0},
  {0, 0, -3}
 } )
```

like in the equation. If I calculate this by hand I get this result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `Simplify` or `Expand` the results.

Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= a = {{2, -2, -4}, {-2, 5, -2}, {-4, -2, 2}}
Out[1]= {{2, -2, -4}, {-2, 5, -2}, {-4, -2, 2}}

In[2]:= p = {{1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -(2/3)}, {-(2/Sqrt[5]), 2/(
   3 Sqrt[5]), -(2/6)}, {0, x5, -(2/3)}}

Out[2]= {{1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -(2/3)}, {-(2/Sqrt[5]), 2/(
  3 Sqrt[5]), -(1/3)}, {0, x5, -(2/3)}}

In[3]:= sol = 
 Solve[Inverse[p].a.p == {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}]

Out[3]= {{x5 -> -(Sqrt[5]/3)}}

In[4]:= Inverse[p].a.p /. sol[[1]]
Out[4]= <big output removed>

In[5]:= Simplify[%]
Out[5]= {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}
```

`Expand` would work too in place of `Simplify`.  Expressions in terms of roots and fractions can often be written in several ways, and it's not immediately obvious if two expression are equivalent just by looking at them.  You have to explicitly ask Mathematica to transform them, for example `expr = 13/(2 Sqrt[3]) - 4/3` and `Together[expr]`.

---

**What is quite strange though**, is that `Solve` does not work if you use the standard syntax and give variables explicitly:

```
In[6]:= Solve[Inverse[p].a.p == {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}, x5]

Out[6]= {}

In[7]:= Solve[
 Inverse[p].a.p == {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}, x5, 
 VerifySolutions -> False]

Out[7]= {}
```

Can anyone explain why?  `NSolve` works as expected.

```
In[8]:= NSolve[
 Inverse[p].a.p == {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}, x5]

Out[8]= {{x5 -> -0.745356}}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed this also. When I say Solve[...,x] It did not work!, strange, I am looking at it now.

Comment: What I do not understand, is why are we using  `{{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, -3}}` in the RHS? There are 3 equations, and so the RHS should just be `{6,6,-3}`. When I do that, I get extra solutions for x. Please see my reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove["Global`*"];
a = {{2, -2, -4}, {-2, 5, -2}, {-4, -2, 2}};
p = {{1/Sqrt[5], 4/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/3}, {-2/Sqrt[5], 
    2/(3 Sqrt[5]), -2/6}, {0, x, -2/3}};
pInv = Inverse[p];
lhs = pInv.a.p;

q = {6, 6, -3};
eqs = N@Expand@
   Map[Total[lhs[[#, All]]] - q[[#]] == 0 &, Range[Length[q]]]
```

Here are the 3 equations all in x.  (3 equations, ONE unknown!)

```
-6. - 2.66667/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) + (4.47214 x)/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) == 
  0., 

-6. - 2.66667/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) + (4.47214 x)/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) == 0., 

 3. - 0.654283/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) -(1.5694 x)/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) + (
   4.47214 x^2)/(-0.444444 + 0.745356 x) == 0.
```

first solve numerically

```
 Map[NSolve[eqs[[#]],x]&,Range[3]]

 Out[465]= {{{x->0.}},{{x->0.}},{{x->-0.745356}}}
```

To get Solve to accept `x`, First do not do Numerical, leave it symbolic:

```
eqs = Expand@ Map[Total[lhs[[#, All]]] - q[[#]] == 0 &, Range[Length[q]]]
```

which gives

```
{-6 - 8/(3 (-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3)) + (2 Sqrt[5] x)/(-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3) == 
  0, 

-6 - 8/(3 (-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3)) + (2 Sqrt[5] x)/(-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3) == 0, 

 3 + 4/(3 (-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3)) - (8 Sqrt[5])/(9 (-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3)) 
 + (2 x)/(3 (-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3)) - (
   Sqrt[5] x)/(-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3) + (
   2 Sqrt[5] x^2)/(-(4/9) + (Sqrt[5] x)/3) == 0}
```

Now use Solve, with explicit `x` in there, now it is ok

```
Map[Solve[eqs[[#]], x] &, Range[3]]

{{{}}, {{}}, {{x -> -(Sqrt[5]/3)}}}
```

--Nasser